# How do I get column name from rowselection in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a extjs gridpanel setup, and I want to be able to do things based on a user clicking on text or icons in the grid. For example, filter the grid if the user clicks (or double clicks) a word in a column, or show a popup if the user clicks on an icon. I can easily get the row they clicked on, and values by column name from that row, but I don't know which column was clicked.

Alternatively, I could add an onClick to the entire grid, which I could then get the individual text from the row/column, but I don't know what row index or column that value belongs to. I could add a CSS class that would tell me a column name, but that seems like a hack.

Is there anything built-in that can do this?

Comment: The following post can throw some helpful light:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083004/getcellrow-col-in-gwt-htmltable/8571224#8571224

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ["cellclick" event](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel&member=cellclick) on the grid is the way to go. A function listening on this event gets passed:

- `( Grid this, Number rowIndex, Number columnIndex, Ext.EventObject e )`

If you want to get the text of the gridCell, calling `yourGrid.getView().getCell(rowIndex, colIndex)` will return the DOM element.

If you want to get the column header, call: `yourGrid.getColumnModel()`.[`getColumnHeader(colIndex)`](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel&member=getColumnHeader)

If you want to find anything else out about a particular column, call `yourGrid.getColumnModel()`.[`getColumnAt(colIndex)`](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel&member=getColumnAt)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are interested in column wise events rowselection is the wrong event to look into. As Joshua suggested the [cellclick](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel&member=cellclick) event will the event you have to look into.

This event can give the dataIndex of the column as given

```
var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at edit-grid.html example for checkbox rendering and event handling.