# getCell(row,col) in GWT HTMLTable

Tags: gwt, html-table, flextable

There is no such method in HTMLTable:

```
Cell c =  getCell(row,col);
```

What is the most effective way of getting a cell in an HTML/Flex Table, given the row and column?

Comment: should have asked that before answering, but better late than never: are you talking about `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable.Cell` `com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell<C>`?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do.

If you want to read/write the content of the cell, you might want to use `HTMLTable#setText(int,int)` and `HTMLTable#getText(int,int)`, or `HTMLTable#setWidget(int,int)` and `HTMLTable#getWidget(int,int)`, if the content of the cell is a widget.

There are more functions to read/write properties of the cell in `HtmlTable.CellFormatter` ([link to gwt javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.CellFormatter.html)) and its subclasses - you can obtain it using `HTMLTable#getCellFormatter()` and maybe cast it, depending on the implementation of `HTMLTable` you are using. with the cell formatter you can, for example, set/remove styles, attributes or get the underlying `Element` ([link to gwt javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html)) for even more direct control.

Comment: I am not asking for alternatives to Cell. I have reasons for getting a Cell, reasons beyond this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

[HTMLTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html) has the following methods:

- `HTMLTable#isCellPresent(int row, int column)`
- `HTMLTable#getWidget(int row, int column)`

You could write a utility method using both of them like this:

```
public static Cell<?> getCell(HTMLTable table, int row, int column) {
    if (table != null && table.isCellPresent(row, column)) {
        Widget widget = table.getWidget(row, column);
        if (widget instanceof Cell) {
            return (Cell<?>) widget;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because Cell is an interface to a TD not a widget. e.g. TextInputCell is an implementation of a Cell. My HTMLTable has no widgets.

Comment: Do you have an example? If you're using HTMLTable.Cell it's only intended for `HTMLTable#getCellForEvent` and all of the `add(...)` widgets in `HTMLTable` take an `IsWidget` as a parameter? If you are using `HTMLTable.Cell` you'll need to expose the constructor and combine it with some casting (e.g. `TableElement table = TableElement.as(htmlTable.getElement()`) and iterate through it to re-create your cell.

Answer (score 0):

I di the below code to register the mouseover event whcih will fecth the value of any cell you hover and display it in the tooltip. you can modify the listener for a click and get the same stuff.My code for the event is:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();   
  grid_plancode.on('mouseover', mouseOver);


function mouseOver(e, tar){
  var t = e.getTarget();
  var overCell = grid_plancode.getView().findCellIndex(t);
  var overRow = grid_plancode.getView().findRowIndex(t); 
var selectedText=grid_plancode.getView().getCell(overRow, overCell);
           if(overCell !== false && overRow !== false) {
Ext.QuickTips.register({target:tar,title:'Value', text:selectedText. innerText }); 
}
```